# mvc webApi, why application start again?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, durandal-2.0, application-start

I work in durandal Project, which built on mvs web api.

However, some-time it arrived to function Application_Start (in Global.asax) again, at running time.

Why?! It must happen once, when first request arrives to server!

For example, in Application_Start  I init some classes singlotone-intance, and they are initialized again! It's not good for my application!

Comment: Post your `Application_Start` code.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal occurrence in web-application.
If it not good for you, consideration the option of save data at your data-base.